# How to override the handlePan selector in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tvos, uipangesturerecognizer

In my tvOS app, I am trying to listen to changes in scrolling of my UICollectionView. After research, I found that the collection view natively receives a few gesture recognizers among them a UIPanGestureRecognizer with the selector `handlePan`:

```
<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x101a4c1a0; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UICollectionView 0x1020c5d00>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UICollectionView 0x1020c5d00>)>>
```

in the log, or in code:

```
myCollectionView.panGestureRecognizer
```

I was wondering if there's a way to add my controller as the target of the gesture recognizer, or maybe override the `handlePan` method.
I tried implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but it does not give me an access to the `handlePan` method.
Maybe I should just add a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of my own on the collection view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView so you can detect scroll changes on collectionview by adding scrollview delegates.

Objective-C

```
// called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

}

// called when scroll view grinds to a halt
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

}
```

Swift

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```